# Cannot read property 'Symbol(keypress-decoder)' of undefined node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, process

I'm working onto STDI/O for the first time. I'm adding two numbers to prints the sum to STDOUT. Reading the input from STDIN. The first line of input will contain an integer (N) that tells how many more lines there are in the input. Each of the subsequent N lines contain 2 integers). And print the sum of each pair on a separate line of STDOUT.

```
                    const readline=require('readline');
                const readlinInterface=readline.createInterface(process.stdio,process.stdout);
                addNumber();




                async function addNumber(){
                    let length=await inputValue("please enter the value for N numbers to be added");
                    let sum = await addValue(length);
                    console.log("sum",sum)
                }



                async function addValue(length){
                    let num,sum;
                    let i;
                    for( let i=0;i<length;i++){
                        num[i]=await inputValue("Enter num");
                        sum+=num[i];
                    }
                 return sum;
                }

                function inputValue(text){
                    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                        readlinInterface.question(text,resolve)
                    });
                }
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong when I run **node  add.js** the error thrown as ** Can not read property 'Symbol(keypress-decoder)' of undefined **  it points here

```
       readline.js:1047
     if (stream[KEYPRESS_DECODER]) return;
```

I'm stuck past two days can anyone please help. Any help is appreciated.

**Updated:**

```
                    const readline=require('readline');
                const readlineInterface = readline.createInterface({
                    input: process.stdin,
                    output: process.stdout
                  });   

                   function add (){
                    readlineInterface.on('line',(val)=>{console.log("reading",val)

                    });
                  }

                 readlineInterface.on('line',(numberLength)=>{console.log(numberLength)
                    let i=numberLength;
                    let sum;
                    while(i){
                        console.log("i",i)
                       // add();
                        readlineInterface.on('line',async (val)=>{ console.log("reading1",val) });
                    readlineInterface.on('line',async (val)=>{ console.log("reading2",val) });
                      i--;
                    }

                });
```

Yet doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [usage of the createInterface function](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options)

Actually, NodeJS tries to get the input stream from the "input" property but finds nothing and [then tries to use the stream (undefined)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/205046af7eb6be0b4a7a785082962586ed6f1dec/lib/readline.js#L1123)

```js
const readlineInterface = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
```

Answer (score 0):

But there is no "data" event. Please check [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_class_interface)

Probably, you need [the 'line' event](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line)